# Linear Algebra Proof: If a transformation is linear, then the transformation is also a matrix transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

How do I go about writing a proof for the following linear algebra question:

If a transformation is linear, then the transformation is also a matrix transformation.

I'm looking to involve some math formulas and/or matrices to prove this.  I'm really stuck and googled online but couldn't find anything specific.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you know about bases?

Comment: You need a definition of *linear transformation* to prove this.  For example, if someone says "the definite integral over some interval $I$ is a linear transformation from the space of all real-valued integrable functions on $I$ to $\mathbb R$" then it may require some thought on how a matrix transformation is meaningful for this.  If on the other hand you are are restricting the idea to linear transformations $f:R^n \to R^m$ then it may be easier

Comment: Are you allowed to assume every vector space has a basis? Because the proof needs part of the axiom of choice... unless you're working with spaces of obviously countable dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the question that you mean to ask is this:

> Suppose that $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is a linear transformation.  Prove that there exists an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ such that for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$, $T(x) = Ax$.  In other words, $T$ is the "matrix transformation" associated with $A$.

Here's a proof.

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$ (i.e. the columns of the identity matrix). Let $A$ be the matrix whose columns are $T(e_1),\dots,T(e_n)$.

Consider any vector $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)^T \in \Bbb R^n$. We find that
$$
\begin{align}
T(x) &= T(x_1 e_1 + \cdots + x_n e_n) = 
x_1 T(e_1) + \cdots + x_n T(e_n)
\\ & = \pmatrix{T(e_1) & \cdots & T(e_n)} \pmatrix{x_1\\ \vdots \\ x_n} = Ax.
\end{align}
$$
So, $T(x) = Ax$ for every $x \in \Bbb R^n$.

Comment: lifesaver!  thank you :)